# Runtime error: Either a replica set or a mongos is required to guarantee message delivery

Tags: mongodb, openstack

I am installing openstack-zaqar on ubuntu server 14.04 (vmware) as given in the guide http://docs.openstack.org/developer/zaqar/development-environment.html.

Everything worked fine until I used the command "zaqar-server -v", when I received a long error much part of it looked like it meant "Either a replica set or a mongos is required to guarantee message delivery". I have made all the changes as mentioned in the guide, but I am still unable to understand and resolve this issue. Attached is the screenshot of the issue!

[image: Output on zaqar-server -v]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been hit by the exact same problem while trying to set-up and play with zaqar.
Make sure, that your config contains

```
unreliable=True
```

Mine looks like:

```
[DEFAULT]
unreliable = True

[drivers]
message_store = mongodb
management_store = mongodb

[drivers:message_store:mongodb]
uri = mongodb://192.168.99.100:27017

[drivers:management_store:mongodb]
uri = mongodb://192.168.99.100:27017
```

Also, feel free to ask around on Freenode in #openstack-zaqar room, they are very helpful.

Edit: add this so Zaqar listens on all the interfaces, and not just on the loopback address (127.0.0.1)

```
[drivers:transport:wsgi]
bind = 0.0.0.0
```

(This will be necessary once you finish poking around Zaqar locally, and want to dockerize it, or control it remotely.)

Comment: I tried using unreliable=True. Then It worked! Now I am receiving a connection refused error on the curl command which is mentioned next in the guide.. Did you receive it too?

Comment: Interesting, it should work, are you running zaqar in a docker container or locally?

Comment: locally. It finally started working! There was an issue with internal port used.